# architecture/design for web application with lots of ajax call to another server?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, architecture, reverse-proxy

I am not able to visualize or think about the architecture for the below requirements:

1. I need to have almost fully functional web application on HTML-Javascript.
2. I need to have some server side language (C#) for purpose like DB call and maintain state at server
3. I don’t have control over the 3rd party server..so I cant convert it to jsonp to address same origin policy

Most of the Ajax request will go to another server so I am thinking of using reverse proxy at server so all request will be passed to another server as itis (is this server configuration only?).

How should I go about it:

1. Should I make MVC web application?
2. How does reverse proxy come into play in the scenario?

Based on Robert’s reply if I go with MVC app then Who will forward the request from my home server (serving html/js/css) to 3rd party server? Should I configure my IIS server to transfer the request directly to 3rd party server (something like this eg: blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/…) or my server side part (C#) will make that request to 3rd party server

Comment: you've described about 90% of all web apps. Why is yours any different? Doesn't seem like you've done any research whatsoever

Comment: Probably reverse proxy server with rest of web app confusing me.

Comment: use jsonp, no proxy needed

Comment: i dont have much control on 3rd part server...i should have added this to requirements

Comment: then you should be asking specic questions regarding things like how to handle proxy...after you do some research. This is not hard to find on web

Answer (score 1):

You say "Most" of the requests, and "almost" fully functional web application ..this means you will need some server side interaction.

Otherwise, why bother with routing the requests in the 1st place, simply create a HTML/JS only web-app that's independent and autonomous and that communicates via JSONP (works anywhere) or XDR (not supported everywhere)

What you probably want is a ASP.NET MVC website, eventually with areas for maintaining different modules, and also handling skinnability, globalization and features like image resizing and serving specific content to mobile optimize the site for certain features via DisplayModeProvider.

---

The hook up scenario could look like this

Client (Browser)

<- talks with -->

Server (IIS/MVC) serving html/css/js via Views, and regular communication via jsonresult or webApi

| forwards -->

Server (Distant) where any additional requests are processed and which can be connected via WCF endpoints, or SOAP/XML (from previous server) or wrapped in asynchronous webrequests (in previous server).

---

Something like that make sense to you ? Sorry for the ugly text schema :-)

Comment: It does make some sense to me:). However I have one doubt. Who will forward the request from my home server (serving html/js/css) to 3rd party server?  
Should I configure my IIS server to transfer the request directly to 3rd party server (something like this eg: http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx) or my server side part (C#) will make that request to 3rd party server

Comment: I would say your server-side part makes that request. URL rewriting and reverse proxy could be a cool trick to hide the real destination and probably be way more CPU efficient than handling the traffic yourself. But if you don't need to hide the destination you could also simply code your client app to make Ajax request directly to the appropriate server ...yours or theirs. Also need to consider error handling, the first suggestion is probably the simplest to implement and you get to handle all errors yourself.

Comment: The article you point to is routing between 2 internal servers, not sure things are as simple when dealing with external ones. But definitely something interesting to look into